# Post log error of application from android

Tags: java, android, logging

I'm currently developing an application that records the GPS location of the user every X minutes and upload the data to a server. For me, the application works great for days.
I've been testing it on some users and they say the app crashes every few hours but I've been unable to reproduce this.
How can I log this errors and upload them to my server so I know whats going wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: try [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264645/how-to-save-logcat-contents-to-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on the Play store, it should upload them to your developer console.  Otherwise, use a 3rd party library like ACRA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ACRA(Application Crash Report for Android) tool to get the errors whichever has been occurred at the client side. You can refer the below links to get more idea about it.

1) [Link 1](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)
2) [Link 2](http://guidogarcia.net/blog/2011/12/20/acra-reporting-crashes-in-your-android-application-the-easy-way/)
3) [Link 3](http://www.helloandroid.com/content/acra-application-crash-report-android)