# Display Android Logs inside the Text File

Tags: android

I am working to a Android Application where i have to generate text file if for example user shake his handset or crash happens. I want to store Log Report of application( which is also displayed by Logcat) inside this report. Also i want to display specific logs of my company SDK. Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some third party services such as bugsense if cost is not an issue. Or register for crashlytics (free) and wait for acceptance.

Try this.
[How to save LogCat contents to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264645/how-to-save-logcat-contents-to-file)

Comment: We were using Acra API before but my company want to implement everything from scratch. Is there is some class in Android which can give me Logs on Runtime?

Comment: The Link you send is helpful..Thanks