# Print logs of Android emulator in a file

Tags: android-studio, android-logcat

Is there any way to print the logs of Android emulator in a file?

I want to do this when the Android Studio is not running, maybe by using adb.

Comment: Seems [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264645/how-to-save-logcat-contents-to-file)

Comment: It ain't a clone. Please read the description. I want to get the logs of emulator when the Android Studio is not running.

Comment: Ok, you run an emulator and close your android studio. But you can still run [`adb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8264663/3422245)

Comment: I want to get the logcat!

Comment: Please, run `adb devices` - can you see emulator device? If so, then you can run `adb logcat`

Comment: Thanks. `adb logcat` works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save LogCat contents to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264645/how-to-save-logcat-contents-to-file)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this, on Windows 7, which worked best for me: there is a file adb.log somewhere in your user directory. In my case it was located in C:\users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp . If it isn't there, you probably find it by searching your users\[username] directory for adb.log . The log messages from the emulator are there, at least they were in my case.
Once you find it, you can view it using Notepad; it will usually be in use by another application (probably adb.exe, via which the emulator gets its messages there) but Notepad doesn't mind, it creates a read-only copy. If you actually want to copy it to another file you can do a copy-paste; in my case I actually wanted to see its contents, specifically the emulator messages.