# Save logcat data to internal memory

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to save logcat data in internal memory? Thanks for help. I need to save user logs to detect the problem in bluetooth connection.

Comment: Do you mean save logcat to a file on the device?  If yes, some of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264645 explain how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the logcat into a `.txt` file on the device with integrating a class in you application. Here is a good [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565685/saving-logcat-to-a-text-file-in-android-device/37541596) to follow along. A really excellent solution to do so. Cheers.